# Handle Exceptions from ImageMagick with Subprocess

Tags: python, error-handling, imagemagick, gif

I have a subprocess call convert from ImageMagik to slice a gif into frames, but when it encounters a bad gif like this one ( http://www.image-share.com/upload/3207/277.gif )

```
try: 
    command = ["convert" , "-coalesce", "-scene" , "0" , infile, outfile]          
    output,error = subprocess.Popen(command, universal_newlines=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate() 
except: 
    print "%%% convert failed Up" 
else: 
   print "*** converted"
```

I never get an exception. the files are not created and printing output and error result in NULL

When you do the same command from the command line you get this error:

```
convert -coalesce examine.gif video.png convert: corrupt image examine.gif' @ error/gif.c/ReadGIFImage/1368. 
convert: no images definedvideo.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3252.
```

So it does output an error message - but I can't seem to trap it! Is there a work around for both bad gifs and for getting the error output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest evaluating the `subprocess.Popen.returncode`. In this example, any none-zero response should be thrown (or raised).

```py
try: 
    command = ["convert" , "-coalesce", "-scene" , "0" , infile, outfile]          
    child = subprocess.Popen(command, universal_newlines=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output,error = child.communicate() 
    if child.returncode != 0:
      raise Exception("Oops")  # Although you should use a better Exception + message
except: 
    print( "%%%% convert failed Up")
else: 
    print( "*** converted")
```